# Issue with casting String to decimal in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

I have a column in a data set that contains a currency indicator and the corresponding amount of that currency (i.e USD 35,000.05). I am trying to get the substring of the column containing the number and convert it to a decimal. However, whenever I convert it, it only returns the first two digits of the number I am trying to get.

For example, this is what happens:

[image]

In this sample, this is my query:

```
    SELECT 
       SUBSTRING(`Annualized Opportunity Amount`,1,3) as `test1`,
       (SUBSTRING(`Annualized Opportunity Amount`,5)) as test2,
       case when SUBSTRING(`Annualized Opportunity Amount`,1,3) = 'AUD' 
              then CAST(SUBSTRING(`Annualized Opportunity Amount`,5) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) 
       else 0 END as `test3`
    from annualized_opportunity_revenue
```

Is there any reason as to why only the first 2 digits of the test2 column would be returned in test3? The substrings for the resulting value are the same so I don't understand why casting it would alter the data.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does it help if you remove the comma from the substring?

Comment: You need to replace `,` first, `12,345` isn't a number. Store number as number, then there will be no problem.

Comment: Try `select cast(replace(dacolumn, ',' , '') as decimal(10,2))`

Comment: Wow, didn't even think of that. Makes total sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the comma from the string before casting it to a number:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(`Annualized Opportunity Amount`,',',''),5) AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```